# How to do query_posts on tags pages

Tags: loop, query-posts, tags

So I am using the `tags.php` on my WordPress site to create special featured pages; what I would like to do is create a featured area on the index of every page that contains the first five posts.

I have a similar featured area on the homepage that uses sticky posts; but in this case I just want to have the first five posts in the featured loop and then the rest in the normal loop.

I have tried much googling and looking at WordPress documentation but failed. Here is the code I am using for the featured area: (however if I try to put it on the tags page it just creates another home loop)

```
    <?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()) { ?>         
<?php query_posts(array('post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts'))); ?>
    <?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
        <article class="sticky">
            <div class="desc">
                <h2 class="header">Featured Post:</h2>
                <h2><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><?php the_title(); ?></a></h2>

                <?php the_content(''); ?>

                <ul class="post-info">
                    <li><?php the_time('jS F Y'); ?></li>
                    <li>Posted in <?php the_category(', '); ?></li>
                    <li><a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>#comments"><?php comments_number('No Comments', '1 Comment', '% Comments' );?></a></li>
                </ul>
            </div>
        </article>
    <?php endwhile; ?>

<?php wp_reset_query(); ?>
<?php } ?>
```

Comment: Never use `query_posts`, it's bad practice with real and significant practical problems. `query_posts` doesn't modify the query, it replaces it with an entirely new one. Use the `pre_get_posts` filter instead if you need to modify the query WordPress uses, or `WP_Query` if you want to make a completely new query

Comment: @TomJNowell any examples of how to use this on the tags page to create two loops?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is the source of all your problems:

```
<?php if(is_home() && !is_paged()) { ?>         
    <?php query_posts(array('post__in'=>get_option('sticky_posts'))); ?>
```

This takes the current query, and puts it to one side, and places a new query in its place. Here you're saying that you want to show the first page of sticky posts. You said nothing about tags or categories, etc, remember, computers do exactly what you tell them, and you said nothing about the context you're in.

So what you want is the first 5 posts to be marked differently from the rest. So instead of:

```
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    // it's a post! display things!
}
```

Do:

```
$counter = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    $counter += 1;
    if ( $counter <= 5 ) {
        //  it's one of the first 5 posts! display the special top 5 post!
    } else {
        // it's a post! display things!
    }
}
```

Alternatively, when you reach the 6th post, exit the loop and start a new one:

```
$counter = 0;
while ( have_posts() ) {
    $counter += 1;
    if ( $counter > 5 ) {
        break; // we've already shown 5 posts! Exit this loop and start the next one!
    }
    the_post();
    //  it's one of the first 5 posts! display the special top 5 post!
}
while( have_posts() ) {
    the_post();
    // it's a post! Display the post!
}
```

Going back to your `post__in`, if you want to only show sticky posts, you should use a `pre_get_posts` filter to modify the arguments passed in to the current query to include your `post__in` argument. There's a number of very good answers elsewhere on the site on how to use `pre_get_posts` so I won't duplicate them here.

As a side note, never use `query_posts` under any circumstances. I know a number of employers who would consider a sighting of `query_posts` in commercial code a serious event, and a lot of review processes will reject code containing it outright for very good reasons. Use the `pre_get_posts` filter if you need to modify what is shown on a page, and if you need a separate query to grab posts, e.g. for a sidebar widget etc, use a `WP_Query` object. `query_posts` is kept inside WordPress mainly for legacy reasons. Sadly a lot of tutorials out there mistakenly recommend its use